# how to create html css, java script sample in node webkit with windows os

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I dont have idea about node webkit with window os. can you please help me step by step procedure to create html,css, javascript sample with node webkit and how to build the node webkit application

Comment: why cant you ask this question to google ?

Comment: @sarath some one already working in this platform. so i ask this question i  am already browse but i cant clearly so i am asking